# Unable to create a Label in a new col with existing rules

Tags: python

I want to create a new col which indicates High, medium or Low, based on the values from existing col.

SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZID3O.png)

```
import numpy as np
df_s9['T4 Label'] = np.where(df_s9.iloc[:,3].astype(float)<=5.4,'low', np.where(df_s9.iloc[:,3].astype(float)> 5.6 and df_s9.iloc[:,3].astype(float) <11,'Normal', df_s9.iloc[:,3].astype(float)>11,"high")
```

Comment: You should edit this to expand the snippet of code into a full [mcve]; it doesn't currently run (looks like it's missing both some `import`s and some variable declarations). Also, don't forget to describe what's happening with your current code, and what you'd expect it to do instead.

Comment: Also maybe use a small example to better describe what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using loc and assign values like so:

```
df_s9.loc[df_s9['3'].astype(float) <=5.4, 'New_column_name']=="Low"
```

As per the attached picture, statement like above should work fine for you

Comment: It does not have column names, we have 0 1 2 3 and 4, also getting the below error when executing the code posted by me.ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: @sravanipvn You said in the question that you have an existing column and in comment that you don't have a column. Do you have a column or not?

Comment: See I have a DF, I need to add labels in a new col, I'm trying to use np.where with multiple conditions

Comment: @sravani pvn I have made an edit. As per the attached image of data, my answer should work fine for you. If you still face trouble, please attach the data set in the question. I will help you out with that.